# Is it possible to create a database/table/view alias?

Tags: teradata

Let's say there is a database owned by someone else called `theirdb` with a very slow view named `slowview`.  I have an app that queries this view regularly, but, because it takes too long, I want to materialize it to a table within a database that I own (`mydb.materializedview`).

Is there a way in Teradata to create an alias database object so that I can go like `select * from theirdb.slowview`, but actually be selecting from `mydb.materializedview`?

I need to do some rigorous testing against their view, but it's so slow that I hardly have time to test anything.  The other option is to edit the code so that it reads from `mydb.materializedview`, but that is, unfortunately, not an option in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata does not allow for you to create aliases or symbolic links between objects.

If the object is fully qualified by database name and view name in the application your options are a little more restricted. You have have to create a backup of their view definition and them place your materialized table in the same database. This would obviously be best done during a planned application outage.

If the object is not fully qualified by database name and view name in the application and relies on a default database setting or application variable you have a little more flexibility. If all the work is done at a view level you can duplicate the environment in another database where you plan to have a materialized version of their `slowview`. Then by changing the users default database or application variable you can point it at the duplicate environment to complete your testing.

Additionally, you can try to cover (partially or fully) the query that makes up the `slowview` by using a join index. This allows you to leave the codebase as it is in the application but for queries that can be satisfied by the join index the optimizer will use the join index. Keep in mind that a join index does incur a cost as it is in essence a materialized version of the SQL which was used to construct it. This means additional IO and change management issues have to be taken in to account.

Lastly, you could try to create additional secondary or hash indexes on the objects within the `slowview` to improve it's performance.

Comment: Their views are indeed fully qualified and hardcoded in our app, so I can't use default database.  I also don't own their views, so modifying indexes wouldn't work.  This leaves your possible join index solution, but I think I am out of luck there because the views are fully qualified in code.  I've asked the owners to rename their views and then recreate them as materialized tables with the old names on a temporary basis.  We'll see if that works, but I'll take your answer that aliases/symbolic links are not possible in Teradata.

Comment: The addition of a join index, hash index or secondary indexes do not necessarily require any code modifications in the existing view to implement. Do you have a non-production environment that you can test within?